# Problema al instalar Sylius en el servidor

Tags: symfony3, sylius

Estoy utilizando [Sylius](http://sylius.org/download) en digitalocean dentro de mi droplet y uso este código:

```
composer create-project -s beta sylius/sylius-standard acme
```

Se descarga todo perfecto pero al utilizar esto:

```
php bin/console sylius:install
```

Me muestra el error:

> Could not open input file: bin/console

Existen varios archivos que no se descargan dentro de la carpeta bin.

Intente utilizando git haciendo un clone y luego utilizar la misma instrucción pero me da un error en el **autoload.php**

Lo raro es que descargo como root, no se si existe alguna configuración adicional para prohibir la descarga de archivos sin extensión o algo así

Alguna solución??

Saludos

Comment: ¿Es posible que `console` esté dentro de la carpeta app en lugar de bin? Por otro lado, siempre puedes ir al repo del componente y traerte el script de forma manual.

Comment: No. Sylius trabaja con la versión 3.x de Symfony y ya siempre se coloca en la carpeta bin . Lo raro es que descargo como root, no se si existe alguna configuración adicional para prohibir la descarga de archivos sin extensión o algo así

Comment: He probado a instalar Sylius con el mismo comando y el script console está en el directorio bin/ ¿Te has asegurado que efectivamente no está el fichero? Puede que sí esté y sea un tema de permisos.

Comment: Lo revise y no está, de modo local todo bien pero en el servidor a pesar de ser root no lo descarga. Por eso también pregunte al proveedor al respecto. Talvez aca ya le pasó alguna persona algo parecido por eso puse la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré para este problema, aunque un poco largo fue ideal.
Es ejecutar todo en modo local y pasar todos los archivos vía `ssh`.

Los archivos importantes en este caso los que son relevantes son los de la carpeta `vendor`.

Asegurarse que se está utilizando la versión de PHP 5.6 o superior, limpiar cache y funciona.

Espero les ayude.